# LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri (Capistrano to DigitalOcean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, nokogiri, digital-ocean

I am trying to push my Ruby on Rails project to DigitalOcean by using Capistrano.

I am following this guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

I followed every steps, and everything was fine  until I reached step 7 which I run:

```
cap production deploy:initial
```

on my local machine. This command gave me this error:

[image]

I dont know whats wrong but anyways, this is my local machine configuration:

- Windows 8
- ruby 2.0.0
- rails 4.2.3

and this is my DigitalOcean configuration:

- Ubuntu 14.04 x64
- ruby 2.0.0
- rails 4.2.3

Comment: please make sure you have executed `bundle install`

Comment: @Prashant4020 you mean in my local machine? I have already done that...

Comment: On `Ubuntu 14.04` also you need to do the same

Comment: @Prashant4020 but that seems impossible as I use Capistrano to deploy my rails. See here: https://goo.gl/lOAqHn . Where should I run the bundle install on this server?

Comment: @Prashant4020 I have read this guide here: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/deploy-rails-apps-with-capistrano and it says that I should run the "bundle install" on the last release folder which is after I run "cap production deploy"

Comment: The wierd thing is, I never install nokogiri for this app and never include in in the gemfile as well. So, I dont understand why suddenly i got error about this gem?